# How do we create a generic mapping dataflow in datafactory that will dynamically extract data from different tables with different schema?

Tags: azure, u-sql, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a azure datafactory mapping dataflow that is generic for all tables. I am going to pass table name, the primary column for join purpose and other columns to be used in groupBy and aggregate functions as parameters to the DF.
[parameters to df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ6mj.png)

I am unable to refernce this parameter in groupBy
[Error: DF-AGG-003 - Groupby should reference atleast one column -
MapDrifted1 aggregate(
) ~> Aggregate1,[486 619]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV5BB.png)

Has anyone tried this scenario? Please help if you have some knowledge on this or if it can be handled in u-sql script.

Comment: Can you show what you have done? like with some snapshot of your mapping dataflow. it will be more understandable.

Comment: i wouldnt do anything with u-sql. it's not even supported in adla2

Answer (score 3):

We need to first lookup your parameter string name from your incoming source data to locate the metadata and assign it.

Just add a Derived Column previous to your Aggregate and it will work. Call the column 'groupbycol' in your Derived Column and use this formula: byName($group1).

In your Agg, select 'groupbycol' as your groupby column.